# bracket notation does not work with aframe

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

When using A-Frame, it not not possible to access component named with a dash, like "orbit-controls".

I am trying to access aframe component "orbit-controls". Link below:

[aframe-orbit-controls component](https://github.com/supermedium/superframe/tree/master/components/orbit-controls)

since this component's minAzimuthAngle and maxAzimuthAngle is not working so I have to access its source to use script to change it. But when I tried to access it, I cannot use

`var componentAngle = el.components['orbit-controls'];`

to get the component and it returns undefined. When I log

`var componentAngle = el.components`

, it returns:

[image: orbit-controls component exists]
So how can I access this "orbit-controls"? I also tried

`var getAngle = el.getAttribute('orbit-controls');`

which returns

[image: data of "orbit-controls" component]
and these are only numbers and changing them wont change the real minAzimuthAngle. So I am wondering if there is a way to access the property showed in the first image? Very much appreciated.

Below is the code link.

[try to access "orbit-controls" component](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/ahead-belly?path=index.html:36:25)

Answer (score 1):

You should wait until the entity is fully loaded before grabbing `this.el.components['orbit-controls']`:

```
this.el.addEventListener('loaded', e => {
   console.log(this.el.components['orbit-controls']
})
```

The **azimuth** component is added before **orbit-controls** so when the first one is being initialized, the latter might not be ready yet.

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1h0mojtr/).